# Dryer Vent Rough-In - New Construction - Stucco

Tags: dryer, stucco, rough-in, lathe

I'm a DIY'er doing a complete to the studs remodel. I'm getting tripped up on a minor detail that I would prefer to get right. My goal is to get the dryer vent pipe penetration properly flashed and installed.

I am getting ready to call for the stucco contractor to lathe in prep for stucco. My question is what state do I leave the dryer vent penetration at before lathe & stucco? I don't want to come back and cut it in after stucco because I want the penetration properly flashed at the sheathing & WRB. Because the actual dryer box vent and pipe *(image below)* that installs from the outside after the fact needs to be slipped *OVER* the last piece of vent pipe coming out to the end of the wall, it seems that if I flash and stucco a piece of 4" vent pipe hanging out of the wall, then trim to proper length after, I won't be able to push the vent hood and pipe over the last section of vent pipe as desired. I feel I'm missing something? How is this normally done?

The images below are the components I'm using.

I have 1/2" sheathing on 2x4 stud exterior walls with a Tyvek HomeWrap. I'm using 4" rigid for the dryer vent.

[image: Dryer Vent Hood]
[image: Quickflash Wall Penetration]

Comment: Looks to me like that box vent includes pipe that goes all the way through the wall.  Whatever it needs to join up with gets done inside the house, judging by the photo.  I've never seen that flashing gizmo before.  Looks great but you can just use a foam gasket or silicone behind the box vent flange.  It's vertical, right?  If the outside wall is being stucco'd you can probably get the stucco guy to embed the vent flange into a smooth area of stucco surrounding it, to make a good interface with a foam gasket or silicone.

Answer (score 1):

On the stucco jobs I put the exhaust in prior to stucco so it covers the flange then work to the dryer with a short piece of flex at the dryer itself so the dryer can be pulled out. If you put it in later it won’t look as nice and more chances for cracking as you will need to punch holes in the stucco to mount it.
I have seen them done both ways. With the vent in first if the hood gets damaged and a replacement is needed it’s more work. If the stucco’s is completed and the fasteners crack the stucco you have that and the exposed flange.  So there are pros and cons for each method.